# Is it known whether Wightman's axiomatic QFT is logically equivalent to Osterwalder–Schrader's axiomatic QFT?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, mathematical-physics, wightman-fields

[Constructive QFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructive_quantum_field_theory) has provided some interesting models for dimension $d < 4$ of space-time, satisfying specific axiomatic versions of QFT. On the other hand, it is a well known fact that an axiomatic theory can admit more than one model, the question here would be: is it known whether there are models that satisfy Wightman's set of axioms but not those of Osterwalder and Schrader, or vice versa?

Comment: Anything that satisfies OS must satisfy W, by the original OS reconstruction theorem. OS also originally had a theorem published that proved equivalence in the other direction too, but it ended up containing a mistake in the proof, afaik it is still not proved that any wightman QFT has an OS interpretation. I will write a more detailed answer with references later, have to run now unfortunately